# DefaultValue in Entity Framework Core does not work

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am having a problem when generating a default value with Entity Framework Core, it is supposed to generate a `getdate()` value but it does not work.

This is what I have in my fluent Api

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Loteria>()
    .Property(p => p.FechaCreacion)
    .HasColumnType("datetime")
    .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()")
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
    .IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<Loteria>()
    .Property(p => p.FechaModificacion)
    .HasColumnType("datetime")                
    .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()")
    .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
    .IsRequired();
```

I have also tried like this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Loteria>()
    .Property(p => p.FechaCreacion)
    .HasColumnType("datetime")
    .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()")
    .IsRequired();

modelBuilder.Entity<Loteria>()
    .Property(p => p.FechaModificacion)
    .HasColumnType("datetime")                
    .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()")
    .IsRequired();
```

But all I get is:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+
>   <>c.b__108_0(Task result)
>
> DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch+d__32.MoveNext()

Comment: Have you tried removing `.IsRequired()` as well?